Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...): unable to load shared object
I'm new to R but not statistical programming and keep getting the same error after looking to use R, RStudio, and Rtools. I rolled back to R 4.3.0 with RStudio 2023.3.0 and Rtools 43 based on some AI suggestions but it's all still throwing the same error and don't know where to go next. I need the stats package to be able to run analysis and import files. Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated as this is putting a halt to data review.
Setting enviornmental variables, rolling back to versions stated to be more stable
Stable on first install/review but not anytime after
full error:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Hi, welcome to SO. Please format posts using markdown. Tutorial here. Also, please as much information as possible to get more useful help. Here, I would add the code you used to generate the error and the output of sessionInfo().
